# Hide page Id in url

Tags: wordpress

In a page, I have href that links to another page in my website, using page id: `"/?=page_id=xxxxx"`.
The href page itself have url that not contain page Id in the URL for exemple:

- pageID of about-page: 4321
- the href links to- homepage/?=page_id=4321
- the permalink in the about page is: homepage/about

The problem is that when clicking the href it recognize what page is that id and send me to about page but in the url its says: `homepage/about/?page_id=4321`.

How can I keep the href like it is and remove page id while it going to href's page

Answer (score 0):

go on wp-dashboard choose the settings < permalinks and replace the page id option to post name
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNFyM.jpg)

Comment: its already like this

Comment: make sure is this option is here

Answer (score 0):

in admin panel

Go:

**Settings » Permalinks**

and active :
**post name**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTpVH.jpg)

Comment: its like the image already..